# How to reference externally defined node modules with string identifiers with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm writing a set of `node` helper modules in `typescript`. I'm having difficulty getting typescript to interpret type information for external node modules such as "fs" and "path".

Importantly, I want to separate my module into a bunch of Typescript files, with a class/interface per file. They file layout is like this:

- `ts/ISomeInterface1.ts`
- `ts/ISomeInterface2.ts`
- `ts/SomeClass1.ts`
- `ts/SomeClass2.ts`

A class instantiates one or more interfaces, and is written as follows:

```
///<reference path="IFileSystemHelpers.ts" />
var fs = require("fs");
namespace myNmspace {
    export class SomeClass1 implements SomeInterface1 {

        public someIFunction() {
            //do work
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) to install type declarations for NodeJs. And I use a `tsconfig.json` file to build and reference these external typings. Here's a snippet:

```
{
    "version": "1.8.9",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
            "out": "./outputfile.js"
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "./**/*.ts",
        "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "files": [
        "./typings/main.d.ts",
        "./ts/ISomeInterface1.ts",
        "./ts/ISomeInterface2.ts",
        "./ts/SomeClass1.ts",
        "./ts/SomeClass2.ts",
        "./ts/exports.ts"
    ]
}
```

Then classes are exported in the `exports.ts` file:

```
declare var exports: any;
if (exports) {
    exports.SomeClass1 = myNmspace.SomeClass1;
    exports.SomeClass2 = myNmspace.SomeClass2;
}
```

Then comes my problem. How do I get type information for the "fs" module?

I can see the following in the `node.d.ts` file (see [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts))that `typings` has installed:

```
declare module "fs" {
    import * as stream from "stream";
    import * as events from "events";
...

}
```

How do I force Typescript to interpret my `fs` variable in the `SomeClass1.ts` file as strongly-typed? In other words, what do I write here:

```
var fs : ??? = require("fs");
```

Can anyone help?

---

*As an aside, I've noticed that if I replace the `var` with an `import` keyword, I get correct type interpretation for the `fs` variable. However the terms which point to my interfaces break and I get a squiggly line under the `implements ISomeInterface1`. Changing the pattern to use `imports` breaks my file separation, and seems valid only if I want to create a single-file node module.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ES6 style imports

```
 import * as fs from 'fs'
 import * as path from 'path'
```

This will also import the definitions from the definition file.

The syntax `var x = require('x')` does not (however `import x = require('x')` does, to add to the confusion)

Comment: Thanks Bruno. But - as I said in the aside - using ES6 imports means that my references to outside classes and interfaces (e.g. in `///<reference path="ISomeInterface.ts" />`) no longer work. So I am no longer able to reference `ISomeInterface` in the `SomeClass1.ts` file.

Comment: I understand. The short answer is (this is a comment): use external modules and do not mix, especially as you have set `commonjs`. See [this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html) and comment at the bottom of § 3.4

Comment: But, using the import format, how do I reference the ISomeInterface or ISomeClass2 from the SomeClass1 file. `import * as m from 'ISomeInterface'` isn't working for me

Comment: Ok. I've solved it. I was using the wrong syntax. I needed to use `import { ISomeInterface }from "./ISomeInterface";`

Comment: Yes. You got it. `Import * as m from './ISomeInterface'` would have worked too using `m.ISomeInterface` in the rest of the module